# I want to be able to have Levels as a currency in my realm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to get the problem that players might die and loose their hard earned levels? I don't really want to use keep inventory. Is there a specific command?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `keepInventory`? It's easier to just clear the inventory with commands after death: `/clear`

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions (like 1.13.2) you can use:

> /xp add JohnDoe -1 levels

to take away one experience level from a player. You can change the number and the username to anything you want, but make sure the number is a negative.
Keep in mind that it doesn't work for older versions, like 1.8.
You can couple this up with a /give command, for example, in order to give the player an item in exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think that storing their level in scoreboard and then giving it back will work.